# Module 'ConvenienceKit' has no member named 'removeObject'

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am getting an error in my project: `Module 'ConvenienceKit' has no member named 'removeObject'`.

I can't seem to figure out what's missing. I made the function `public` which did nothing. Maybe I could initialize the property? If so how?

```
public func removeObject(object: T) {
  ConvenienceKit.removeObject(object, fromArray: &self.content)
  currentRange.endIndex = self.currentRange.endIndex - 1
  target?.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

My full error message:

`/Users/nikolai_georgie/Downloads/Makestagram-Swift-Solution-master 2/Frameworks/ConvenienceKit/ConvenienceKit/ConvenienceKit/UIKit/TimelineComponent.swift:90:5: Module 'ConvenienceKit' has no member named 'removeObject'`

Comment: It isn't possible to answer the question without the source code of ConvenienceKit, bust based on the error i'd guess that the message is accurate..ConvenienceKit has no class function called removeObject.

Comment: The error message you have does not refer to your own removeObject function so making it public will, as you've found, have no effect. The error message refers to the first line inside your function. This line - ConvenienceKit.removeObject(obj -  ConvenienceKit is the class, not an instance of the ConvenienceKit class type, so to call removeObject on the class the class must have removeObject defined inside it as a class function. I'm assuming you didn't write ConvenienceKit? In that case you are probably not supposed to call the function on the class but on an instance of the ConvenienceKit.